# Routing traffic to aws services without using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I am working on a solution that is using amplify for the web app with cloudfront as cdn , for the backend the api gateway is invoking aws lambda functions .
The client does not want us to manage the dns using Route 53 .
The problem here is that , if we manage to do this with cloudfront , how to use the same domain for the api gateway endpoints too ?

Comment: Depending on what "does not want us to manage the dns using Route 53" means, you could create a CNAME pointing at a Route53 record/api gateway endpoint? Otherwise you're probably into writing lambdas, etc to update DNS records in your client's preferred DNS management system.

Comment: Thanks @DanielScott for your reply , Do you mean That I have to create a Route 53 record for my API Gateway endpoints and one for my CloudFront Url , and then use these records as CNAME within the DNS management System (This DNS Management System is managed by a third party, not us) ?Or just communicate these urls to the other third party so they can add them to their DNS Management System as CNAMEs?

Comment: It would depend on the control you wanted. And other things such as tls certs. If you add more detail to your question then I may be able to help